# how to search joomla members on joomla front page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I was wondering if I could i ask the best way forward. I am making a joomla site which will have an advanced registration form. Which I am planning to create with rsform pro. What would be the best method for people to able to search those registered users on the front page .

Any other method that one could or would advice rather than rsform pro like some extension that would ease both the registration and searching as a single component. The search function also needs to be multi optioned. I am trying to take the most informed decision before I start with the coding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Easy Profile does a great job of this:

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easy-profile

See the example at https://www.easy-profile.com/users-list.html for a searchable user list.

You'll need the paid version for custom fields.

[image: Easy Profile Users List]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try [JoomProfile](http://www.function90.com/products/joom-profile.html). Is seems quite useful extension for joomla user profile management. If also has good and fast search http://demo.function90.com/joom-profile/search-in-joom-profile.html

Answer (score 0):

Joomla already has some search components, so the best thing to do is to use it. Actually there is two components that you can use

- Search, based on com_search component which do the work on the fly
- Advanced search, based on com_finder component which index data and give it back after, it is more efficient and has more functionalities

In both case, you'll have to write a plugin to search user, joomla doesn't  have it by default (or you can search some on joomle extensions).